# Invalid project description when importing project into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I know this question is posted already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084056/invalid-project-description-importing-from-git-repo-problem), but that doesn't solve my problem.

I pull a project from github branch, and when i try to import it : `File->Import->General->Existing projects into workspace` then `Select root directory` and here when i click on `Finish` button i get `Invalid project description`.

I am pulling the project into a folder called `Android`, this folder contains the main folder of the project `MyAndroidProject` which i imported in Eclipse.

I don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace or any other information?  Kind of hard to tell from the information you've provided.

Comment: What are the contents of its .project file?

Comment: Good afternoon, look out the link [Invalid project description][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784652/eclipse-invalid-project-description-when-creating-new-project-from-existing-so/13458004#13458004

Comment: You may get this error if your code is already checked out in the workspace folder. You need to check it out to a different location. This may or may not be the problem here.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I know I'm late to the party, but just in case someone else is stuck at this point, just like me a couple of minutes ago: You could try File>Import>Existing Android Code into Workspace. I had the Git repository I wanted to import directly in my workspace. Still, I needed to check the **Copy projects into workspace** option in order to make it work.

**Edit**

I just checked out the link from one of the comments above, recommending File>Import>General>Existing Project into Workspace. I should mention that the eclipse project metadata was not under version control in my case, rendering an import as existing project impossible! This solution applies to existing android code without .project files etc.

**Edit 2**

Just another remark: I realized recently that this issue only seems to occur if the *project root* also is the *repository root*, much like this:

```
workspace  
└─ project root  
   └┬ .git
    ├ src
    └ ...
```

When I moved the project just one directory level lower, the issue disappeared.

Comment: i don't kw how but it works for me if i move my project to one level below anywayz +1 for you :)

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for the upvote! It kind of surprised me as well. I noticed that when I added an Android test project to my repo, for which I had to move things one level down.

Comment: Yep, the moving project one dir down fixed the issue.

Comment: WARNING! Eclipse just set *all* of the files, in the project that I imported with the option "Copy projects into workspace", to 0kb !! This crap should *never* happen.

Comment: Your solution safed me from lots of fustration. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Just move the project folder one directory lower ( make another folder in the directory & copy your project into that folder. Now import the project with this newly created version. )

Answer (score 3):

Had same issue, changed the workspace to one directory above the project and then imported project. Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I've just read this very old question. The problem is in the Eclipse specific folders.

Simply remove .settings and .project and reimport.