# Can't clone eclipse project into workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit

I'm using Eclipse Juno to develop a java project cloned from bitbucket but when importing the project from my bitbucket repository using Egit eclipse plugin I get this error : `Invalid project description`

I deleted the project folder and retried to clone using `git clone` and after importing the project to workspace I get the same error !!

can anyone help ?!

Comment: have you seen this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084056/invalid-project-description-importing-from-git-repo-problem

Comment: yes .. but this doesn't help cuz I'm working in an empty workspace

Comment: Can you edit your question to put the detailed error?

Comment: Please confirm the existence of a file named ".project" in the root folder for the project.

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish between a Java project and an Eclipse project. Not every Java project is already a Java project and not every Eclipse project is a Java project. You can recognize an Eclipse project by the files that exist. An Eclipse project contains a file `.project` and a folder `.settings`. In this files the Project settings and metadata (e.g. if it's a Java project) are saved.

Make sure if the project you want to check out is an Eclipse project or a plain Java project.

It seems to me as if it is not but you try to import it as such. If it is not an Eclipse project you should import the project using the "New Project Wizard". Choose `Java project` and you'll be fine.

Eclipse will now create the project configuration files. If you commit your changes, make sure you ignore those files. You don't want them in your repository because they contain system specific settings which might not work with other machines. This is the reason why you most likely won't find Eclipse projects in repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a project in Eclipse and clone it from repo